# Remove rows with NAs in all columns except specified columns

Tags: r, na

I’ve looked around quite a bit but having a difficult time adapting previous answers to this case. I have something similar to the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("ID1" = c(1, 2, 3, 4), "ID2" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), "var1" = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), "var2" = c(NA, NA, 2, 3), "var3" = c(NA, 4, 5, 6))
```

I’d like to remove rows with NA values in all columns except for the first two. I have many more variables than just var1, var2 and var3 and would be great if I didn’t have to specify them. The output should look like this:

```
result <- data.frame("ID1" = c(2, 3, 4), "ID2" = c("b", "c", "d"), "var1" = c(NA, NA, NA), "var2" = c(NA, 2, 3), "var3" = c(4, 5, 6))
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
df[!rowSums(is.na(df[, 3:ncol(df)])) == (ncol(df) - 2), ]
```

Or reverse:

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[, 3:ncol(df)])) > 0, ]
```

Output:

```
  ID1 ID2 var1 var2 var3
2   2   b   NA   NA    4
3   3   c   NA    2    5
4   4   d   NA    3    6
```

And a `dplyr` option with reverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter_at(-(1:2), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Reduce` in `base R`

```
df[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[-(1:2)], is.na)),]
#  ID1 ID2 var1 var2 var3
#2   2   b   NA   NA    4
#3   3   c   NA    2    5
#4   4   d   NA    3    6
```